# Flutter - Firebase - Android - Heads-up notification

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, flutter

I am currently building an App with googles Flutter framework and I would like to have a heads-up notification using Firebase. I am using the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/firebase_messaging) package  to receive messages from firebase in Flutter. I get the notifications but I was not able to show heads-up notification in the Android App using Flutter. Does anybody know if its even possible or is flutter currently limited to "normal" notifications since Android data messages are not supported when the app is terminated?

Comment: Heads up notification, do you mean the notification fully shown at the top of the phone screen?

Comment: And you can receive and parse data notification even if the app is terminated writing some native java code for android. If you need help on that, I can give you some guide as an answer.

Comment: example heads-up notification: [Figure-3](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications).
Right now my notifications appear in the just as little symbol in the notification tray. They appear larger when the phone is locked though! I think android introduced some restrictions for heads-up notifications - [restrictions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications) .
If you did something similar before I'am more than happy to get some advice!

Comment: @tobsen did you ever figure out a solution?